# struct in header compilation error

Tags: c, compiler-construction, mpi, header-files

I'm trying to write a framework library which wraps MPI.

I have a header file for the framework call `afw.h` and an implementation file for the framework called `afw.c`.

I would like to be able to write application code which uses the framework by doing `#include "afw.h"` in the application code.

An excerpt from `afw.h`:

```
#ifndef AFW_H
#define AFW_H

#include <mpi.h>

struct ReqStruct
{
    MPI_Request req;
};

ReqStruct RecvAsynch(float *recvbuf, FILE *fp);
int RecvTest(ReqStruct areq);
```

I provide an implementation for `RecvAsynch` in `afw.c` which `#includes afw.h`

When I compile using `mpicc` (an MPI compiler wrapper in this case using pgc underneath):

```
mpicc -c afw.c -o afw.o
```

I get:

```
PGC-S-0040-Illegal use of symbol, ReqStruct (./afw.h: 69)
PGC-W-0156-Type not specified, 'int' assumed (./afw.h: 69)
PGC-S-0040-Illegal use of symbol, ReqStruct (./afw.h: 71)
PGC-W-0156-Type not specified, 'int' assumed (./afw.h: 71)
```

and similar errors wherever `ReqStruct` is used in `afw.c`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined a `struct ReqStruct`, not `ReqStruct`, and those are not the same thing.

either change the function to

```
struct ReqStruct RecvAsynch(float *recvbuf, FILE *fp);
```

or use typedef:

```
typedef struct ReqStruct ReqStruct;
```

Comment: Yes, of course, thankyou. I thought I had discounted this before writing but obviously not!

Answer (score 4):

In C++, the sequence:

```
struct ReqStruct
{
    MPI_Request req;
};
```

defines a type `ReqStruct` that you can use in your function declaration.

In C, it does not (it defines a type `struct ReqStruct` that you can use); you need to add a `typedef` such as:

```
typedef struct ReqStruct
{
    MPI_Request req;
} ReqStruct;
```

Yes, the `struct` tag can be the same as the `typedef` name.  Or you can use `struct ReqStruct` in place of just `ReqStruct` everywhere; I'd use the `typedef` in preference.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment about the C/C++ difference, classic case here of someone who learned C++ first...